# Hierarchical Data Structure WPF TreeListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I am currently writing a WPF TreeListView.
I was wondering a couple of things.

How does the Hierarchical Data Structure work and can the children display other properties instead of the same property as the parent?
Currently I am trying to make a treelistview with the columns

Client  /  Matter / Hours

If i add a client and it has the same matter then
the parent will change it's hours to the total hours to the total amount of hours added up by the children.

Here's an example

I add

John / Writing Paper / 1 hour 
John / Writing Paper / 2 hour 
John / Writing Paper / .5 Hours

My tree list view will show

John / Writing Paper /3.5 Hours < this is the parent 
  -John / Writing Paper / 1 hour 
  -John / Writing Paper / 2 hour 
  -John / Writing Paper / .5 Hours < these are the children

Instead i would like it to show

John / WRiting Paper/ 3.5 Hours 
 - 12:00 am - 1:00 pm / wrote the introduction 
 - 2:00 pm - 4:00 pm / wrote the body 
 - 3:00 pm - 3:30 pm / wrote the conclusion

I am using two observable collections. One which is the parent and one which is the Child.

My question basically is. Can I change the Hierarchical Data Structure to display different properties? Different information. I don't want to be repetitive on showing the same Client Matter Hours.
Instead i would like to show different properties for the child. Since the Parent will be showing who the information belongs to.
Btw, I'm trying to do this for XAML and C#

Thanks in Advance!! 
-Kevin

Answer (score 1):

You can set DataTrigger for the HierarchicalDataTemplate and have different property binding. Just an example below. [Please check this earlier answer in this thread just in case you need more ideas.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719609/wpf-having-hierarchicaldatatemplates-in-a-treeview)

```
 <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local:Person}" ItemsSource="{Binding People}" >
    <Grid>
      <TextBlock x:Name="fName" Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
      <TextBlock x:Name="lName" Text="{Binding LastName}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
   </Grid>
   <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers> 
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="A">
      <Setter TargetName="fName" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
       <Setter TargetName="lName" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
    </DataTrigger>
  </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers> 
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

[Jobi Joy](http://jobijoy.blogspot.com/)

Comment: That won't work, because Hierarchical DataTemplate Only accepts on child right?

Answer (score 1):

If your parent and child are different object types, there is a very easy answer:  Just use multiple HierarchicalDataTemplates in a ResourceDictionary:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Parents}">

  <TreeView.ResourceDictionary>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate
        TargetType="{x:Type my:ParentType}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">

      ... parent content ...

    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate
        TargetType="{x:Type my:ChildType}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">

      ... child content ...

    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

  </TreeView.ResourceDictionary>
</TreeView>
```

This technique does not work in all scenarios, but when it does it is very powerful and expressive.

Another variation on this if the Parent and Child are the same type but with a different parameter is to create an `ItemTemplateSelector` that calls `LoadResource()` to load the appropriate named `HierarchicalDataTemplate` depending on the data values.