# TreeListView Displaying different information than it's parent. WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have tree list view NOT A tree view.

I would like it to display different information than the parent. 
With the different columns

I want to have the parent  to display:

Name Task and Activity code.

The CHild to display

Start Time End Time and Total Hours.

But i would like the child columns to match the parent columns such that

Name and Start Time are under each other
Task and End Time are under each other
Activity COde and total hours are under each other.

I asked this recent post and it didn't work out.

[Hierarchical Data Structure WPF TreeListView DataTriggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752223/hierarchical-data-structure-wpf-treelistview-datatriggers)

Just wondering if anyone else has better suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Have an IsParent property in your ViewModel class and add a DataTrigger in the CellTemplate to disaply  different visual(Binding)