# HierarchicalDataTemplate for very complex layout

Tags: wpf, vb.net, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

Im making a herbal database program and I am having troubles setting up HierarchicalDataTemplates for my main data class.

Tree layout wanted:

- Glossary

  - Category1

    - Letter (Reduces overall list size)

      - Entry

        - Note1
        - Note2
- Herbs

  - Botanical Name

    - Alphabetical

      - Letter (Reduces overall list size)

        - Entry
    - By Family

      - Family

        - Entry
  - Common Name

    - Letter (Reduces overall list size)

      - Entry

NOTE: All entries have notes
NOTE2: Letter is a letter of the alphabet for sorting

Ex:

- a

  - apple
- b

  - bus

Main Class:

```
Public Class MainSystem
    Public herbs As New Dictionary(Of Integer, herbEntry)
    Public glossary As New Dictionary(Of Integer, glossaryEntry)
End Class
```

GlossaryEntry:

```
Public Class glossaryEntry
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Words As List(Of String) 'Each word is in the format: Catagory/word
    Public Property Notes As SortedDictionary(Of String, String)
End Class
```

HerbEntry:

```
Public Class herbEntry
    Public ID As Integer
    Public Property commonName As List(Of String)
    Public Property botanicalName As List(Of String)
    Public Property PlantID As PlantID
End Class
```

EDIT: Thanks to the link from @AngelWPF I have got the tree displaying my object. But, currently the tree looks like this:

- Herbs

  - Common Name

    - CommonName item from entry
    - Another CommonName item from entry
  - Common Name

    - CommonName item from entry
    - Another CommonName item from entry

How can I make this change to match my hierarchy?

XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type my:herbEntry}">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Common Name"  ItemsSource="{Binding commonName}">

            </TreeViewItem>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TreeView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="TreeView1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Herbs" ItemsSource="{Binding herbs.Values}"/>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: I still dont have a complete solution, the link @AngelWPF posted helped alot in getting me started, but i still havent found a way to organize the tree. So far, the only method i can think of is to generate custom node objects in the hierarchy that I need and display that. But thats sounds a little too hacky to me. In some ways, WinForms is MUCH easier...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example may guide you to assign different item templates at different levels for each type of bound item ...

[Having HierarchicalDataTemplates in a TreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719609/wpf-having-hierarchicaldatatemplates-in-a-treeview)

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful. Now I'm having problems getting the catagories and sorting. Updated post with my partial solution