# How to use WPF Data Binding with an MVVM Model to Populate a StackPanel with Custom Controls

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, user-controls

I have a hierarchy of data that looks like this:

- Policy

  - Check

    - Action
    - Action
    - Action
  - Check

    - Action
  - Check

For each Policy/Check/Action, I have a custom control built in WPF.  I have been programmaticly adding new instances of my controls to containers in the parent control.  (IE. When a user clicks the "Add Check" in the Policy control, I will do a `MyPolicy.StackPanelChecks.Children += new CheckControl()` ).  I am converting to an MVVM model and am trying to use data binding to populate this StackPanel (and don't want to embed DataTemplates into my code, especially with a hierarchy of data model objects).

What is the best known way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This looks more like a `TreeView` than a `StackPanel` to me.

In MVVM you bind to the hierarchy and define `HierarchicalDataTemplate`s for each node type.

Have a look at this question: [Having HierarchicalDataTemplates in a TreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719609/wpf-having-hierarchicaldatatemplates-in-a-treeview)