# Deep LINQ projections, how?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Let's say I have a model created with EF 4.0

- User

  - Roles

    - Permissions

Each entity has a DeleteDate property.

I want to get a specific user (with Name =...) and have the tree filled with items where DeletedDate == null..

This must be done with anonymous type projection as result, but I don't know how to accomplish this with a hierachy deeper than 2..

This is what I already have:

```
    public MyProjection MyCall(string givenName)
    {
      var result = from s in context.Users
                   where (s.Name == givenName &&
                                    s.DeletedDate == null)
                             select new
                             {
                                 s,
                                 roles = from r in s.Roles
                                         where r.DeletedDate == null
                                         select r
                             };

      var outcome = result.FirstOrDefault();

      if (outcome != null)
      {
         var myProjection = new MyProjection()
         {
             User = outcome.s,
             Roles = outcome.roles
         };

         return myProjection;
       }

    return null;
   }
```

Comment: The 3rd level: To return all the permissions as a list on each role....

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your structure you could do something like this:

```
        var result = m.Users.Where(u => u.DeletedDate == null)
            .Select( u => new
                            {   
                                u,
                                roles = u.Roles.Where(r => r.DeletedDate == null)
                                               .Select(r => new
                                                   {
                                                        r,
                                                        permissions = r.Permissions.Where(p => p.DeletedDate == null)
                                                   })
                            }).FirstOrDefault(item => item.u.Name == givenName);
```

Comment: How do I get one specific user, with the roles and per role the permissions then ?

Comment: I've updated the code to pick a specific user - however I don't understand what you mean by 'with the roles and per the role permissions'

Comment: The issue is more how to get a tree from user -> roles -> permissions, but then based on the deleteddate filter. I want to return this tree of one user with roles and per role the permission back to the UI...

Answer (score 0):

If you retrieve with the following:

```
 var result = from s in MyUsers
              where s.DeletedDate == null
              select new aUser{
                   Roles = (from r in s.Roles
                            where r.DeletedDate == null
                            select r).ToList()
              };
```

And then create a TreeView:

```
 TreeView treeView = new TreeView();
```

Then set the ItemsSource of the TreeView to the IEnumerable:

```
 treeView.ItemsSource = result;
```

Then build a HierarchicalDataTemplate in your TreeView to represent your Lists ([similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/719840/1466627) or for more in depth [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/davids/archive/2009/06/04/hierarchicaldatatemplate-and-treeview.aspx)), then voila!